# How to mock wrap().assign() of MikroORM when using with NestJS, the objective is unit testing a update method

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, mikro-orm

I have a method like this

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail({ id });
wrap(user).assign(userData);
await this.userRepository.flush();
return await this.readById(user.id);
```

Similar to the one available in this [official example](https://github.com/mikro-orm/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/user/user.service.ts), the example also implements [unit testing](https://github.com/mikro-orm/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/user/test/user.service.spec.ts) for the service, but it doesn't implement a test for the update method.

I'd like to implement a unit test for the mentioned method, but when I try I get the following error

```
(0 , core_1.wrap)(...).assign is not a function
TypeError: (0 , core_1.wrap)(...).assign is not a function
    at UserService.updateUser (C:\Users\DanielMendesSechisnk\Projects\nestjs-rest-api\src\users\user.service.ts:37:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DanielMendesSechisnk\Projects\nestjs-rest-api\src\users\tests\user.service.spec.ts:89:12)
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insted of using wrap().assign() use em.assign()
this will be easier to mock.

```
 const book = await em.findOneOrFail(Book, 1);
 //wrap(book).assign(new_version, { mergeObjects: true }); 
 em.assign(book, new_version, { mergeObjects: true })
 await em.flush();
```

mocked entityManager on specs.ts

```
let entityManagerMock = {
        findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(eventMock),            
        assign: jest.fn(),
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I didn't notice the EntityRepository had this method before

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `MikroORM.init` first before you work with the entities, as that is required for the metadata to be present - and metadata are required for [propagation](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/propagation) to work.

Also note that you don't need to reload entities you update, if you query entity via `em.findOne` with its PK, and it is already loaded, you will get the entity from identity map without any query being made.

```
const user = new User();
em.persist(user);
await em.flush();

// this will return `user` without querying database
const user1 = await em.findOne(User, user.id);
console.log(user1 === user); // true
```